# Display a single image from folder using php

Tags: php, osclass

i am having a issue on my osclass theme. I want to display a particular image from my folder manually. The images are in the folder and i am using this function to display the image, could someone help.

```
  if(!function_exists('aiclassy_draw_ad')) {
        function aiclassy_draw_ad(){
            echo '<div class="advertise_area">
I want my image to be called here
           </div>';

            echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

            </div>';
              echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

            </div>';
              echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

            </div>';

        }
    }
```

Comment: And where are you specifying the image folder ?

Comment: <img src="images/img.png" />

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you need?

```
echo '<div class="advertise_area">
          <img src="http://morelook.com/content/uploads/2011/07/advertise_here_250x250.png" alt="" />
      </div>';
```

**EDIT**

Based on OP comment: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pskxnmu0/)

Turn off your adblocker if you have.

Comment: does not work. I tried but the it shows broken image. I am doing this website in the osclass framework.

Comment: @sanjuwere when you say broken image,, what are you saying ? 404 error ? also nitpicking but osclass is a cms not a framework

Comment: The source of an image tag is the path to the image. Maybe you need to set absolute URI if you are not sure, how can you access relatively. Do not use path like `D:\images\image.jpg`, use `http://example.com/images/myimage.jpg` instead.

Comment: yahh... actually nothing displays. No image.

Comment: @sanjuwere show us your css for advertise_area then.. something is hiding the image... adblocker ?

Comment: try to copy this to your browser: `http://www.yourdomain.com/images/img.png`. Is the image there?

Comment: div.advertise_area{
height: 250px; width: 250px; background-color: rgb(236, 240, 241); vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; line-height: 248px;background-image: url('http://morelook.com/content/uploads/2011/07/advertise_here_250x250.png');
}

Comment: You have a typo: `advertise_here_250x250.png'/` remove the last character.

Comment: well!!! i removed it and the ad space is blank. atleast. So now i want to upload a image in this format <img src="images/inage.jpg" />. How do i do it. Thanks guys for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should place an `image` tag in your `div` tag, like this:

```
  if(!function_exists('aiclassy_draw_ad')) {
    function aiclassy_draw_ad(){
        echo '<div class="advertise_area"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></div>';

        echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

        </div>';
          echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

        </div>';
          echo ' <br /> <div class="advertise_area">

        </div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: i want to upload the image in this format. <img src"images/img.png" />. I dont want to go through any urls. And thank you for your answer.